# Can Ionic encompass multiple Angular apps?

Tags: android, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

On my Angular webapp right now, I have the main app in the `/app` directory, the `signin` and `signup` apps in separate directories at the same level. If the user in the app is detected to not be logged in, he is redirected to the `/signin` app.

The general scheme is

```
myproj
   |- app
   |   |- index.html
   |   |- app.js
   |- signin
   |   |- index.html
   |   |- signin.js
   |- signup
   |   |- index.html
   |   |- signup.js
```

Note that `app.js`, `signin` and `signup` are separate apps not related to eachother in any way except that they redirect to eachother (i.e. after successful sign in, the `signin` app redirects to `/app`.

**I'm worried** about how this will work when I want to convert this into an Ionic app for mobile. Can an Ionic app contain multiple apps that redirect to eachother? Or does everything in an Ionic app absolutely have to be under one single root app?

Comment: Have you maybe made some progress on this?

Comment: @Nikola not yet, I put it on pause, but I will continue with it soon hopefully

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't try something like this myself, but I would be interested to know if (and how) it's possible.